# Where is the proposal on "structural binding"?

Tags: c++, tuples, standards, language-lawyer, c++17

In the following [C++ Going native video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-44-ISOC-Kona-Debriefing#t=18m58s),
there is mention of a language feature called "structural binding".

I had once [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394507/how-can-i-emulate-destructuring-in-c) to this concept as "destructuring" (comming of a javascript background).

The feature will allow users to capture multiple return values without needing to use `std::tie`, or specify the types.

Example:

```
std::map<std::string,int> table;
auto { cursor, inserted } = table.insert({"hello",0});
```

Where can I find this proposal, and track its progress?

Comment: [P0144R0](http://wg21.link/P0144R0). Also a competing proposal - [P0151R0](http://wg21.link/P0151R0). And I'm fairly sure this is off-topic...

Comment: I was searching "structural".  thanks.  @T.C. Then I'm sure SO will be quick to close it.

Comment: I believe this is marginally on topic, I believe a rewording to focus more on the status of this proposal as opposed to where it is improves the question.

Comment: FYI: You could just look at the [collection of all C++ papers.](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proposal you are referring to is [P0144R0: Structured Bindings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf) . The [post-Kona mailing](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/#mailing2015-11) lists this paper as under Evolution Working Group. It is not covered in the current [Evolution Working Group(EWG) active issue list](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html) and Nicol Bolos points out the the EWG active issue list has not been updated for Kona. Once it shows up in the EWG active list then you can track the proposal by tracking the issue.

There are some really good trip reports and in particular [Botond Ballo's trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-kona-october-2015/) covers this proposal under the section *Proposals for which further work is encouraged* and it says:

> A proposal for de-structuring initialization, that would allow writing
>   auto {x, y, z} = expr; where the type of expr was a tuple-like object,
>   whose elements would be bound to the variables x, y, and z (which this
>   construct declares). “Tuple-like objects” include std::tuple,
>   std::pair, std::array, and aggregate structures. The proposal lacked a
>   mechanism to adapt a non-aggregate user-defined type to be
>   “tuple-like” and work with this syntax; EWG’s feedback was that such a
>   mechanism is important. Moreover, EWG recommended that the proposal be
>   expanded to allow (optionally) specifying types for x, y, and z,
>   instead of having their types be deduced.

We can find the WG21 meeting mailing by going to the [WG21 site](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/) and going to the [papers section](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/).

As T.C. notes there is also a competing proposal [P0151R0: Proposal of Multi-Declarators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0151r0.pdf) which says:

> We propose a better approach for “Structured Bindings” as defined in
>   P0144R0 where  “better”  is defined as terser, more ortogonal, more
>   general, more expressive, less (parsingwise)  ambiguous.

Comment: I was going to correct the typo in orthogonal, but then saw the original proposal had that same typo.  Now I'm torn :P

Comment: "more ortogonal [sic], more general,"

sic erat scriptum