# Best way to iterate over pairs of literals

Tags: c++, c++14

This works, but is pretty verbose:

```
for (auto entry : std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>  { {1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {3, 'c'} } ) {
    int num = entry.first;
    char value = entry.second;
    ...
}
```

There's got to be a more elegant way...

Comment: Why does there have to be? Iterating over a container of known type is far more common than iterating over a sequence of literals.

Comment: This is already a lot more elegant than what we'd have to write to do the same thing a couple of years ago.

Comment: In C++ 17 it should be possible: `for ( auto[num,value] : ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I emulate destructuring in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394507/how-can-i-emulate-destructuring-in-c) Doesn't help much though.

Comment: I can change the `std::vector<std::pair<int, char>>` to `std::map<int, char>` which shortens things a little.  Would be nice if there was a way avoid the first / second thing and give meaningful names to them without using two lines, but I'm on C++14 at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 and later, you can make use of [initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) to construct a list of pairs:

```
using std::make_pair;

for (auto x : {make_pair(1, 'a'), make_pair(2, 'b'), make_pair(3, 'c')})
{
    std::printf("%d %c", x.first, x.second);
}
```

In C++17, it's possible to use [structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) and [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to make it more elegant:

```
using std::pair;

for (auto [a, b] : {pair(1, 'a'), pair(2, 'b'), pair(3, 'c')})
{
    std::printf("%d %c", a, b);
}
```